# Increasing muscle mass in my left leg considering the following conditions?

Tags: muscle, injury, recovery, injury-prevention

I had an operation for an ACL tear in my left knee and physiotherapy for tennis elbow in my right hand plus a weird problem in my right wrist.

**What happened because of these** - My left leg looks skinnier than the right.

**What I want to do** is

> 1. Increase the muscle mass of my left leg to match the right.
> 2. Maintain my current level of upper body fitness.

**What I need your help with** is to do these things keeping in mind that I cannot handle/manoeuvre more than 15 kilograms with my right hand in rotational motion.

Please help with the things I want to do. I have 12 years of experience in fighting, martial arts and numerous other endeavors. I have the discipline to do anything.

**What exercises should I perform?**

Available resources - Access to gyms with machines adn weights and stuff. All supplements available.

Comment: What facilities/equipment do you have available?

Comment: @rrirower Hey. I've just added an edit at the bottom. My town has several gyms but I don't know how to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

Years ago, I also had an ACL tear.  I concentrated on a couple of different **isolation** exercises as well as **compound** exercises to try and restore my size and strength.  I used the following exercises:

- 1 legged [RMT squat with an exercise
  band](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OIL2rLNLvog) – you basically
  wrap an exercise band around your knee, attach it to an unmovable
  object, and, squat on one leg.  This will build balance, strength, and size.
  I would tuck my “good” ankle under my glutes when I squatted.
- 1 legged leg extensions.  Make sure to progress slowly with the
  weights.
- Full (2) leg extensions.

I'd also recommend some hamstring work like lying hamstring curls.

You should clear any of these exercises with your PT or personal physician before attempting to do them.